# How to convert zip file into bytes in Java

Tags: java, zip

how can I convert a zip file into bytes?

> ```
>  byte[] ba;
>  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(ba);
>  InputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);
> ```

Comment: You want to convert the entire file or just read it's entries. You current approach would uncompress the contents of the file before been written out...

Comment: I want to convert the entire file.

Comment: So you just want to read a File from disk into a `byte[]`?

Comment: if what @Thilo said is true so you dont need ZipInputStream.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can read a file from disk into a `byte[]` using

```
 byte[] ba = java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(filePath);
```

This is available from Java 7.

Comment: that takes the path, how about if i have the file..not path

Comment: I want to answer but with this one line prefect code there is nothing more to say.

Comment: @user3278732 You can use [`java.io.File#toPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath()) to convert a `File` reference to a `Path` reference

Comment: The only criticism I might make against this (and is super minor), is it's impossible to provide progress feedback, so if the file is large enough, there could be a some delay between calling it and getting the result back. Having said that the maximum size of the file will be limited to the maximum size of `int`...I'm a UI developer, I like feedback ;)

Comment: If the file is large, you should try to avoid reading it into memory, though. Zip files tend to be large. @user3278732 What kind of processing do you need to do that requires the file to be present in memory in its entirety?

Comment: Updated package, byte[] ba = java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

Answer (score 6):

The basic principle is to feed the `InputStream` into the `OutputStream`, for example...

```
byte bytes[] = null;
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("..."))) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read = -1;
        while ((read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    } 
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```